# Uncaught TypeError When Passing Variable from FancyBox Into Parent

Tags: javascript, php, fancybox, parameter-passing, parent-child

i have a problem when i passing variable value from FancyBox. First, i will tell the code :

Here is the code in the FancyBox :

#### JavaScript

```
function post_value(no){
    parent.setSelectedUser(document.forms[no]["NO_INDUK"].value);
    parent.$.fancybox.close();
}
```

#### html

```
while($baris = mysqli_fetch_assoc($hasil))
        {
            //1 item($baris);
        $no++;
?>
        <tr>
            <form name="<?php echo $no ?>" method='post'>
                <td><?php echo $no ?></td>
                <td><input id="NO_INDUK" class="form-control" type="text" name="NO_INDUK" size="5" value="<?php echo $baris["NO_INDUK"] ?>" readonly/></td>
                <td><?php echo $baris["NAMA_SISWA"] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $baris["NAMA_WALI"] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $baris["ALAMAT"] ?></td>
                <td>
                <a class="btn btn-success" href="#" onclick='post_value(<?php echo $no ?>)'> Pilih</a>
                </td>
            </form>
        </tr>

    <?php
         } //untuk while
    ?>
```

Then this is source page view :

#### html source view

```
<tr>
    <form name="2" method='post'>
        <td>2</td>
        <td><input id="NO_INDUK" class="form-control" type="text" name="NO_INDUK" size="5" value="112312" readonly/></td>
        <td>Angga Lisdiyanto</td>
        <td>asa</td>
        <td>asdsad</td>
        <td>
        <a class="btn btn-success" href="#" onclick='post_value(2)'> Pilih</a>
        </td>
    </form>
</tr>

<tr>
    <form name="3" method='post'>
        <td>3</td>
        <td><input id="NO_INDUK" class="form-control" type="text" name="NO_INDUK" size="5" value="2543" readonly/></td>
        <td>Fina Arzika Humaidah</td>
        <td>Nur Kojim</td>
        <td>Campurejo, Panceng, Gresik</td>
        <td>
        <a class="btn btn-success" href="#" onclick='post_value(3)'> Pilih</a>
        </td>
    </form>
</tr>
```

Then when i click the button 'Pilih', the FancyBox won't close and the value is not passed. If the javascript code like this one, it can successfull passing a value :

```
function post_value(no){
    parent.setSelectedUser(no); //just test, passing from no value
    parent.$.fancybox.close();
}
```

After debugging it with Chrome, there are error in this line :

```
parent.setSelectedUser(document.forms[no]["NO_INDUK"].value);
```

And the error message is :

#### Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'NO_INDUK' of undefined

That is, i hope there are any reply and i would be very happy if there are someone can help me out.
Thanks :)

Comment: First, you are repeating the same ID and `name` attributes in different elements through your HTML, when they should be unique. Second, bear in mind that `onclick='post_value(n)'` should pass the index (starting from `0`) of that specific form in the collection and not the form's name. In other words, is not an arbitrary parameter but the chronological number of the corresponding form. Other than that, it should work http://jsfiddle.net/7o2qdr30/

Comment: @JFK Am sorry but it was name="<?php echo $no ?>" so i think it is form's name. So how to solve it?
I am confuse, my eyes is blacked up. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED (with my blacked eyes!).

So as @JFK said, onclick='post_value(n)' is passing form index not the form's name. So i try it out with adding several char in the form's name like this :

```
<form name="form<?php echo $no ?>" method='post' action="">
```

Then in the button is like this one :

```
onclick='post_value("form<?php echo $no ?>")'
```

And on the JavaScript :

```
function post_value(NamaForm){
    parent.setSelectedUser(document.forms[NamaForm]["NO_INDUK"].value);
    parent.$.fancybox.close();
}
```

That is.

Sorry for Indonesian language may confuse you. :)